# CGContextSetTextPosition does not work on Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cgcontext

I was using the following call:

```
CGContextSetTextPosition(context, 0, -bounds.origin.y)
```

After I upgraded to Xcode 8 and Swift 3, I am getting the following error:

> 'CGContextSetTextPosition' is unavailable: Use var textPosition

After going through Apple documentation, I realized the textPosition property is actually a getter that only "Returns the location at which text is drawn." It does not set anything and doesn't seem to have a setter function for text position in the documentation.

What should I do to set the text position then?

Obj-c code is welcome as well.

Comment: According to [the documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext/1454687-textposition), it has a setter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `textPosition` on `CGContext` like this.

```
context.textPosition = CGPoint(x:0, y:-bounds.origin.y)
```

For more deatil read Apple Documentation of [Core Graphics](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext/1454687-textposition) for textPosition.

Comment: Thanks man. I already had a content variable but I was doing it like CGContext.textPosition and it was not working.

Comment: Welcome mate :)